# Merge two arrays alternatively

Tags: php, arrays

What I want is an `efficient` (without looping) way to merge arrays in the way that the `first element of the resulting array` is the `first element of the first array`, `the second element of the resulting array` is `the second element of the second array` (alternatively)... etc

Example:

```
$arr1 = array(1, 3, 5);
$arr2 = array(2, 4, 6);

$resultingArray = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
```

Comment: What's inefficient about looping? Any solution that interleaves the arrays would have to at least go through them once, which is what a loop would do anyway.

Comment: I believe the author of this question uses the word efficient, as not in terms of processing time, but in time of development. He does not want to write the code himself. It would be more efficient if there was a already a function that could do this.

Comment: Is it possible to use `array_merge` to achieve something similar. What I have really is an associative array (key => value), that I want to transform to an array containing alternatively key1, value1, key2, value2...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

assuming both arrays have the same length.

```
$arr1 = array(1, 3, 5);
$arr2 = array(2, 4, 6);

$new = array();
for ($i=0; $i<count($arr1); $i++) {
   $new[] = $arr1[$i];
   $new[] = $arr2[$i];
}
var_dump($new);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'd really advocate this "hack", but this'll do:

```
$result = array();
array_map(function ($a, $b) use (&$result) { array_push($result, $a, $b); }, $arr1, $arr2);
```

It really just hides a double loop behind `array_map`, so, meh...

Comment: this solution is more pythonic (sorry php guys). but it will only work on `Php +5.3`.

Comment: CAUTION: This will replace array keys with number indices.

Comment: @JhourladEstrella Of course it is indexing the the output array.  You are pushing elements from two arrays (which have identical original keys) into a new data structure where duplicated keys are not allowed. p.s. I don't generally like the idea of using `array_map()` when its return value is ignored.

Comment: @JhourladEstrella for associative-safe versions of this technique, see [my answer on the dupe page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69114863/2943403)